# recommended architecture for play framework application with front and back end

Tags: architecture, playframework

I'm looking for a **recommended architecture** for using the **[play framework](http://playframework.org)** where there are multiple servers doing different things but sharing the same model and persistence layer.

Now, the specifics...

I'm looking to create an application which will run on multiple play instances to distribute load. Some instances will be serving web pages to the outside world and others will be performing batch/backend tasks (eg, monitoring queues). Both halves of the application will need to read and write to the database (hence the common model and persistence layer).

*The ideas I've come up with so far:*

**1) same code base on all instances but only some serving**

This idea is to have all the code in one application and deploy the application to several servers, place a load balancer in front of the app servers but only have it distributing the requests to some of the instances. The other instances would be used to perform the backend tasks.

**2) separate out the code**

This idea would be to have the data model and persistence layer in one module, and then a second and third module to handle the front end and back end requirements respectively. The data model module would be a play framework library and would be included in both the second and third module (ie, not deployed separately).

*Does anyone have any suggestions as to how they would implemente a play-framework based application with similar architectural requirements and scaling abilities?*

Answer (score 1):

Put your model in the "app" folder of a play module and share this module between your frontend and backend applications.

Another solution is to put your model your backend application and use some JSON WS call between frontend and backend to retrieve the data